# Using WMSYS.WM_CONCAT with Oracle XE 10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle-xe, ora-00904, wm-concat

When I try to use WMSYS.WM_CONCAT with Oracle XE 10g, I receive a compilation error: `ORA-00904: "WMSYS"."WM_CONCAT": invalid identifier`.  Can anyone verify that this is indeed due to XE lacking this (undocumented) feature?  If so, is there anyway to enable it in XE?

Answer (score 3):

I had found a couple reference sites, but had no luck enabling it. I ended up writing my own function to handle the concatenation.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION CONCAT_LIST( cur SYS_REFCURSOR, sep Varchar2 ) RETURN  VARCHAR2 IS
ret VARCHAR2(32000);
tmp VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
loop
  fetch cur into tmp;
  exit when cur%NOTFOUND;
    if ret is null then
       ret := tmp;
    else
      ret := ret || sep || tmp;
    end if;

end loop;
RETURN ret; END;/
```

Then it can be called as

`SELECT distinct CONCAT_LIST(CURSOR(SELECT id FROM test_table1), ',') test_table1 FROM dual`

Comment: Thanks, I'm really curious as to whether this function can be enabled. The best alternative I found was the User-defined Aggregate Function here: http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php. I renamed the function from string_agg to wm_concat since then I can share stored procedures with my co-workers who have full oracle 10g (the method given in the article allows the same syntax you would use with the real wm_concat -- as long as you are not using scripts which fully qualify wm_concat with wm_sys)

Comment: That is pretty slick. I have a couple of large queries that I am using this function. As soon as I am back in the office I will create the new one and check performance. This has me curious. Thanks!

Comment: Cool, I'd love to hear your performance results when you're done.

Comment: I did some load testing on both functions, CONCAT_LIST and STRING_AGG and found I had to make one modification to my function. I forgot to close the cursor and I maxed out the allowed amount rather quickly. After making the change I created a query that grouped a set of 250 shops to their corresponding type. The CONCAT_LIST completed in 2.68 seconds and the STRING_AGG from oracle-base completed in 0.38 seconds and looks a lot cleaner. I have changed the few queries I had to reference this new function. Here I thought I could help you and you ended up helping me. THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

Source: [link](http://www.sql.ru/forum/531677/wmsys-wm-concat-v-xe).

Just create this function by yourself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE wm_concat_impl
   AUTHID CURRENT_USER
AS OBJECT (
   curr_str   VARCHAR2 (32767),
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT wm_concat_impl)
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      p1     IN       VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       wm_concat_impl,
      returnvalue   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER,
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      sctx2   IN       wm_concat_impl
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE BODY wm_concat_impl
IS
   STATIC FUNCTION odciaggregateinitialize (sctx IN OUT wm_concat_impl)
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      sctx := wm_concat_impl (NULL);
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateiterate (
      SELF   IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      p1     IN       VARCHAR2
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         curr_str := curr_str || ',' || p1;
      ELSE
         curr_str := p1;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregateterminate (
      SELF          IN       wm_concat_impl,
      returnvalue   OUT      VARCHAR2,
      flags         IN       NUMBER
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      returnvalue := curr_str;
      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
   MEMBER FUNCTION odciaggregatemerge (
      SELF    IN OUT   wm_concat_impl,
      sctx2   IN       wm_concat_impl
   )
      RETURN NUMBER
   IS
   BEGIN
      IF (sctx2.curr_str IS NOT NULL)
      THEN
         SELF.curr_str := SELF.curr_str || ',' || sctx2.curr_str;
      END IF;

      RETURN odciconst.success;
   END;
END;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION wm_concat (p1 VARCHAR2)
   RETURN VARCHAR2
   AGGREGATE USING wm_concat_impl;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

It is recommended not to use **WM_CONCAT** since it is an undocumented feature and it has been removed from 12c version. See [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

If you are on **11gR2** and up, use **LISTAGG**.

For version **prior to 11g** where `LISTAGG` is not supported, you could use **ROW_NUMBER()** and **SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH** functions.

For example,

```
SELECT deptno,
       LTRIM(MAX(SYS_CONNECT_BY_PATH(ename,','))
       KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY curr),',') AS employees
FROM   (SELECT deptno,
               ename,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) AS curr,
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY deptno ORDER BY ename) -1 AS prev
        FROM   emp)
GROUP BY deptno
CONNECT BY prev = PRIOR curr AND deptno = PRIOR deptno
START WITH curr = 1;

    DEPTNO EMPLOYEES
---------- --------------------------------------------------
        10 CLARK,KING,MILLER
        20 ADAMS,FORD,JONES,SCOTT,SMITH
        30 ALLEN,BLAKE,JAMES,MARTIN,TURNER,WARD

3 rows selected.
```