# wmsys user/schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have used wmsys.wm_concat in a SQL statement in the SQL Developer and it works perfectly fine.
But now I am wondering whether wmsys functions are available for every user operating on the database. 
Can every user call functions of wmsys?
So if I give the code to someone else are there going to be problems executing wmsys.wm_concat?

Thanks.

Comment: wm_concat is an undocumented function, so it would be better avoiding it; consider that it does not exist in 12c; what oracle version are you in?

Comment: 11g, but I'll look for another solution of my problem then. Better now than in 6 months. Thanks.

Comment: Do not use `WM_CONCAT` since it is an **undocumented feature** and it has been **removed** from the latest **12c version**. Any application which has had been relying on `wm_concat` function will not work once upgraded to `12c`. See [**Why not use WM_CONCAT function in Oracle?**](https://lalitkumarb.wordpress.com/2015/04/29/why-not-use-wm_concat-function-in-oracle/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Oracle 11gR2 you can use [`LISTAGG`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030) to aggregate strings.

`WMSYS.WM_CONCAT` is an undocumented feature that is not available in all Oracle installations (and is [not available at all in Oracle 12c](https://blogs.oracle.com/oracle-database-app-admin/entry/why_not_use_wm_concat)).

Comment: I almost always forget my own Oracle blog, good to see you found it somehow +1

Comment: Thank you a lot.LISTAGG works fine! One last question, is LISTAGG only Oracle version 11g and newer?

Comment: @ThomasKoch Yes, `LISTAGG` was introduced with **Oracle 11gR2**. If you are on a previous release, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32525152/3989608

Comment: One caveat - LISTAGG is a VARCHAR2 return type and so, in SQL, errors out if your list exceeds 4K characters. If that is a worry there are also Tom Kyte's custom analytic STRAGG option, or XMLAGG.

Comment: @MichaelBroughton Yes, `XMLAGG` is the savior in that case http://stackoverflow.com/a/29776515/3989608

Answer (score 0):

There is a decision
[User defined aggregares](https://https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96595/dci11agg.htm/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96595/dci11agg.htm)

This approach permit you use aggregates and concatenation without undocumented functions from wmsys